# Laravel cant read formData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been searching high and low for answers but I cant seem to find.

Trying to send file input to laravel controller via ajax but laravel controller can't seem to read the data at all

Following is my ajax code

```
       let fd = new FormData();
       fd.append('fwigNo' , $('#fwigNo').val());
       fd.append('x' , 27);
       formData = fd;

        $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            url = url.replace(':vdrId', dataId);
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT" ,
                dataType: "json" ,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType:false,
                url: url,
                data: formData,
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result)
                },
            });//end of ajax
        })//end of submit
```

Following is my laravel controller

```
public function store($vdrId , Request $request)
{
  dd($request->all());
}
```

I managed to send to form Data  via ajax but when I dd($request->all()) ,  it shows empty

[image: Ajax Request]

[image: Laravel Response]

Please do advise

update:
Route shown in cmd
[image: route]
Thank you

Comment: see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457

Comment: Why is the formData created outside the submit handler?

Comment: please , show you route list in cmd.

Comment: @ChrisG because there are logic behind that which involves in handling images of type png, jpg and pdf. So it was placed outside . However it doesnt make a difference even if it is inside the submit handler

Answer (score -1):

in web.php route file,try use resource form method get request